# Problem displaying additional fields when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am working on a form whereby I want when the user checks a checkbox additional fields are shown to the user. I am trying to implement the task using jquery but it aint working as expected. I want when the **page loads the text-fields are hidden, when the user clicks the checkbox the 1st input field is displayed, when the checkbox is clicked again the final input field is displayed and the checkbox is disabled**.

Kindly assist?

**Layout**

```
//Checkbox field
    <div class="check-now" style="width: 100%;">
    <label class="spouse-me">
    <h1 class="pumba">Enter next of kin</h1>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark" id="next-kin"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
```

**Additional fields to display when the checkbox above is clicked**

```
<div class="form-line registar2 love">
      <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required>
      <label>First Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-line registar2 move">
      <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required>
      <label>Last Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('input[name="next-kin"]').hide();

    //show it when the checkbox is clicked
    $('input[id="next-kin"]').on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        $('input[name="next-kin"]').fadeIn();
    } 
    else {
        $('input[name="next-kin"]').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle to show the problem?

Comment: both field names are same in your html `input[name="next-kin`

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Am a bit new, dont know to use JSFiddle as for now, you may ask anything I will clarify as per my problem

Comment: @Vel Whats your proposal, do I give them different field names

Comment: @Pweb Check my answer, it's always easier and cleaner to work with classes and ids instead of name attributes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your jquery code like below. I used jQuery 2.1.1.I didn't change the HTML part.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checked = false;
    $(".form-line").hide();
 $("#myCheckBox").on("change", function(){
     if(!checked)
     {
         $(".form-line").show();
          checked = true;
          $("#myCheckBox").attr("disabled","true");// disabled the checkbox
       }
       else{
         $(".form-line").hide();
          checked = false;
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="check-now" style="width: 100%;">
    <label class="spouse-me">
    <h1 class="pumba">Enter next of kin</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox">
    <span class="checkmark" id="next-kin"></span>
    </label>
</div>
    
<div class="form-line registar2 love">
      <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required>
      <label>First Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
</div>   

<div class="form-line registar2 move">
    <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required>
      <label>Last Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>  
</div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Click the checkbox will show the fields and unchecked will hide the fields. See running the snippet

Comment: Khirul Thanks it helps ,,,, I also want when the user clicks again additional fields are shown and the checkbox is disabled...

Comment: @Pweb I have added the disabled part in my javascript in line -8 with comment.Use the updated js part.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong. I added the hidden attribute to the registrar2 divs, this hides them on window load.

Now just show them when your checkbox with id 'checkboxkin' is checked, and you're done!

It's always easier to work with id's and classes instead of name attributes in jQuery.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    //show it when the checkbox is clicked
    $('#checkboxkin').on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        $('.registar2').fadeIn();
    } 
    else {
        $('.registar2').hide();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check-now" style="width: 100%;">
    <label class="spouse-me">
    <h1 class="pumba">Enter next of kin</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxkin">
    <span class="checkmark" id="next-kin"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-line registar2 love" hidden>
      <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required >
      <label>First Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-line registar2 move" hidden>
      <input type="text-area" name="next-kin" class="form-input" required >
      <label>Last Name *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misplaced the input id `next-kin` to a span. Please change the following

```
 <input type="checkbox">
 <span class="checkmark" id="next-kin"></span>
```

To

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="next-kin">
 <span class="checkmark" ></span>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fob8dhm4/)

hope this helps

UPDATE

If the checkbox is need to be disabled, add  `$(this).prop('disabled',true);` inside  `if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {`. Check the updated fiddle for reference.

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fob8dhm4/1/)

Comment: Sure it helps ,,,, I also want when the user clicks again additional fields are shown and the checkbox is disabled...

Comment: where the user clicks again?? same checkbox?

Comment: Yah, the same checkbox,,, other input fields to be displayed and the checkbox to be automatically hidden or disabled. I want only a maximum of 2 fields to be filled by the user...